# Library to get a graphic representation of the blockchain

Tags: blockchain

I'm trying to find a library to make a graphic representation of the blockchain. Something similar to [Gource](https://gource.io/) but instead with git versions, with ethereum

Any idea if something like that exists?

Comment: Can you be more specific? You want to visualize blockchain technologies? or your own one particular blockchain?

Comment: My particular blockchain I mean.

Comment: So in Gource, we track repos and commits, what would you like to visualize for your blockchain.

Comment: If you're considering building a visualization for what a block has, it's transactions, it's very easy and there are a lot of open source codes available. All you need is a search on Github with keywords like "blockchain, explorer, etc.". You can definitely build yours too, as most them use underlying RPC calls to the client (either Geth or Parity) or they use libraries like web3py or web3js.

Comment: However, if you want a visualization tool to track transaction as in who sent to whom, and how much, and upto n-level depth, I'm afraid, but you'll have to build yours. I built one for a proprietary contract, but it can be built using the api calls to your client, some local indexing (for speed) and a library like d3js.